# facebook graph api - some picture not returning correct value

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook graph api in my application. 
One of the functions are to retrieve the page's picture url.

```
$user = 'dvor';
    try {
          $user = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', "", $user);
          $request = new FacebookRequest(
            $this->session,
            'GET',
            '/' . $user . '/picture',
            array(
              'redirect' => false,
              'type' => $type,
              'height' => $height,
              'width' => $width
              )
            );
          $response = $request->execute();
          $results = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

          return $results;
        } catch(FacebookRequestException $fx) {
          //$fx->getCode();
          //$fx->getMessage();
          return null;
        }
```

Now here is the strange thing, for all other $user values that are valid, it is returning the url correctly and the is_silhouette indicator is set to false.

However, when $user = 'dvor', it is returning the default silhouette image.

But here is the kicker, when using the GRAPH API explorer, it is returning a different result:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=dvor%2Fpicture%3Ftype%3Dnormal%26redirect%3Dfalse&version=v2.2&

vs

https://graph.facebook.com/dvor/picture?type=normal&redirect=false

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure that’s the issue here – but in API v2, you can not query user data by username any more, you have to use the app-scoped user id for your app. (And end of April 2015 v1 will be shut of, so you should adapt your code now.)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, the graph explorer allows for me to use a different user_id (or page name). Can you provide more info?

Comment: The page is most likely age restricted. Just us a user access token from a user over 18 or 21 and it will work

Comment: Are you talking about user profiles, or pages here? For the latter, what WizKid just said applies. With you API call in Graph API Explorer, you are most likely using a user access token for your own account, and that is likely to satisfy the age restriction on the page.

Comment: Interesting, however the application is only using an application_token and not a user_token as its requesting public information only. (this was done on purpose). Does that have any impact?

Comment: @WizKid -- Confirmed , you're correct. I've trialed using my own user_token instead of the app_token and it produced the correct results. How do I leverage the app_token to ignore the age limit if that is what it is...?

Comment: You can't. The only way to get it is to use a user access token. Or the page access token for that page

Comment: Thanks WizKid, I'll need to look for another method. I am thinking of running a cron job with a user_token that is valid that will localize the images to get around this obstacle.